# How do I extract test coverage from the istanbul text-summary reporter with a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, code-coverage, gitlab, istanbul

Gitlab CI requires you to specify a regex to extract the statements code coverage (so that they can display it). Given the build output below (with jest and istanbul), I've managed to come as far as: `/Statements.*(\d+\%)/`

```
... (other build output)
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 53.07% ( 95/179 )
Branches     : 66.67% ( 28/42 )
Functions    : 30.99% ( 22/71 )
Lines        : 50.96% ( 80/157 )
================================================================================
... (other build output)
```

This highlights the part `Statements   : 53.07%` (see here: http://regexr.com/3e9sl). However, I need to match only the 53.07 part, how do I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I need to match only the 53.07 part,

Use lazy `.*?`, add `(?:\.\d+)?` to also match floats,  and access the capture group:

```js
var re = /Statements.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%/; 
var str = '... (other build output)\n=============================== Coverage summary ===============================\nStatements   : 53.07% ( 95/179 )\nBranches     : 66.67% ( 28/42 )\nFunctions    : 30.99% ( 22/71 )\nLines        : 50.96% ( 80/157 )\n================================================================================\n... (other build output)';
var res = (m = re.exec(str)) ? m[1] : "";
console.log(res);
```

Note that `Statements.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%` also allows integer values, not only floats.

**Pattern description**:

- `Statements` - a literal string
- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than whitespace, but as few as possible
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1 (the value you need will be captured into this group) capturing 1+ digits and an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits after it
- `%` - a percentage sign (if you need to print it, move it inside parentheses above)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK4jI7/1).

Comment: Ah yes I see. What's confusing is that your pattern highlights the same as my pattern on regexr, but when I hover over the group it show that it only captured `53.07`, so it works as it should from what I can tell, right?

Comment: Just tested this with gitlab, and I can confirm it works. Thanks!

Comment: Do not pay attention to what online testers say. Trust what you get in the end in the *target environment*.

Comment: Note you can even use [`/Statements.*?(\d+\.\d+)%/`](https://regex101.com/r/mZ3dN8/1) if the number always have a fractional part.